# Codigo de para pegar o maior numero bugado?

Tags: java

Criei o codigo que esta na imagem  para percorrer uma lista duplamente encadeada e pegar o maior token(numero do No), e enviei a seguinte entrada(add no fim) : 12, 17, 14, 23, 8, 10. Deveria ser removido 23 e quando chamasse novamente o metodo removeria 17, mas esta removendo 10 e 23. O que ha de errado?Eh bug? ou erro meu?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class ListaNOrdenada {
    private No inicio;
    private int tam;
    private No fim;

    public void add(Integer num) {
        No n = new No();
        n.setToken(num);
        if(tam == 0) {
            inicio = n;
            fim = n;
        }else{
            fim.setProx(n);
            n.setAnt(fim);
            fim = n;
        }
        tam++;
    }

    public No remover() {
        No aux = inicio;
        No maior = inicio;
        int i = 0;
        while(aux.getProx() != null) {
            if(aux.getToken() < aux.getProx().getToken()) {
                maior = aux.getProx();
                System.out.println("maior: " +maior.getToken());
            }
            aux = aux.getProx();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("maior: " +maior.getToken());
        if(maior == inicio) {
            inicio = inicio.getProx();
            inicio.setAnt(null);
        }else if(maior == fim) {
            fim = fim.getAnt();
            fim.setProx(null);
        }else{
            maior.getAnt().setProx(maior.getProx());
            maior.getProx().setAnt(maior.getAnt());
        }
        tam--;
        return maior;

    }

    public void imprimir() {
        No aux = inicio;
        System.out.println(aux.getToken());
        while(aux.getProx() != null) {
            aux = aux.getProx();
            System.out.println(aux.getToken());
        }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Coloca o código no post ao invés de subir uma imagem dele que a gente ajuda.

Comment: Ai esta a classe com os metodos, vai precisar das outras tb?